# How to use regex to reject metacharacters

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, server-side

I have been trying to reject these metacharacters ^ $ \ / ( ) | ? + * [ ] { } >< from all of my textboxes in a form.

This is what I have and it does not reject the characters. It rejects anything typed into textbox3.

```
Imports System.Text.RegularExpressions

Partial Class Default2
Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

Protected Sub company(source As Object, e As ServerValidateEventArgs) 
    If Not Regex.IsMatch(TextBox3.Text, Regex.Escape("^$\/()|?+[]{}><")) Then
        e.IsValid = False
    Else
        e.IsValid = True
    End If
End Sub
End Class
```

Please help me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

2 methods to check if the text contains any of the regex metacharacters:

**Method 1: Using Regex**

The metacharacters need to be put inside a character class `[...]`. Therefore, only some of the characters need to be escaped, ie: `^`, `\` and `]`.

```
    If Regex.IsMatch(TextBox1.Text, "[\^$\\/()|?+[\]{}><]") Then
        ' Invalid input
    Else
        ' Valid
    End If
```

**Method 2: Using `IndexOfAny` String function**

This method doesn't use Regex so, there is no need to escape.

```
    If TextBox1.Text.IndexOfAny("^$\/()|?+[]{}><".ToCharArray) > -1 Then
        ' Invalid input
    Else
        ' Valid
    End If
```